# Whatsapp style - keyboard appear under the toolbar

Tags: ios, keyboard, toolbar, whatsapp

How do I do it whatsapp style, where the message space, when clicked, would push a keyboard up from the bottom, as well as pushing the toolbar up as well. And then when cancelled (i.e. clicking in the background), it'll push the keyboard back down with the toolbar

Answer (score 2):

This is done with the U`IKeyboardWillShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` notifications.
Then when you handle the notification you adjust the height of the frame:

For example:

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = [aValue CGRectValue].size.height;

    self.keyboardVissible = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.contentView.frame;
        frame.size.height -= keyboardHeight;
        self.contentView.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

You will need to register to receive the notification, you should only listen to the keyboard notification when the view is visible, strange thing could happen if you do it in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: what is fetchedResultsController?

Comment: actually i still don't get it self.keyboardVissible is what?

Comment: It's just an extra `BOOL` I use to keep track of wether the keyboard is visible.